# Finding a direct sum of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P(F)$ be the vector space of all polynomials over $F$. Let $W=\{p(x) \in P(F) : p(0)=p(1)=0\}$. I am given that W is a subspace. Find a subspace $U$ such that $P(F) = U \oplus W$.

My attempt:

We need to find a subspace U such that W $\cap$ $U =$ {0} and P(F) = $\{u + w : x \in U, w \in W\}$.

My intuition tells me that W is the set of all polynomials with roots at x = 1 and x = 0. So we're missing all polynomials with non zero roots at x = 1 and x = 0 and all non zero constant polynomials.

Hence $U = \{h(x) \in P(F) | deg(h(x)) = 0\} \cup \{p(x) \in P(F) | p(0) \neq p(1)\}$.

I'm having trouble proving this is a subspace which makes me doubt that U is correct. I've spent a couple hours thinking about this problem so hopefully somebody could double check my intuitions here.

Comment: Indeed, your $U$ is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your description of $W$, and your intuition that we need to somehow "fill in" the missing polynomials is also right. However, it it is not as simple as merely taking all polynomials outside of $W$ and hoping that this describes a subspace. Remember that we only need to be able to **add** the elements of $U$ to those of $W$ in order to produce the missing elements.

As a hint, consider the following: note that $W$ consists of all multiples of the polynomial $w(x) = x(x-1)$. With polynomial "long-division", we can write *any* polynomial $p(x)$ in the form
$$
p(x) = q(x) \cdot w(x) + r(x).
$$
Clearly, $q(x)\cdot w(x)$ is an element of $W$. What is the smallest subspace of $P(F)$ that contains a remainder $r$ for each $p$?

*(In fact, there are many possible answers here that are equally "small", i.e. two-dimensional. However, one of these choices is probably more intuitive than the others.)*

Comment: That was totally what I was missing. Thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Define $U$ as the set of all polynomials of degree at most $1$.